# TYPO3 Rewrite Extension URL tx_xyz to another name

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl

I have a TYPO3 extension for content output. If I call the contents, the name of the extension is always called:

```
example.com/?tx_nameoftheextension[id]=1234
```

The number 1234 is a changing ID. I would like a resolution of the extension to:

```
example.com/detail/1234
```

I tried a little bit, but the following syntax does not work for me:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tx_\nameoftheextension\[id\]=1234$
RewriteRule .* example.com/detail/1234? [R=301,L]
```

Of course the upper one would work with RealUrl, but only with database connection, I would like to solve this without.

But this is only the beginning, I have different display options in the extension which append a longer extension name, which I would like to rewrite that didn´t run with RealUrl:

```
example.com/?tx_nameoftheextension[action]=showN&tx_nameoftheextension[n_id]=1234
```

to

```
example.com/detail/n/1234
```

Try with this `.htaccess` syntax:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tx_\nameoftheextension\[action\]=showN&tx_\nameoftheextension\[n_id\]=1234$
    RewriteRule .* example.com/detail/n/1234? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `^tx_\name` – what’s with the backslash here, what exactly is that supposed to escape here? `n` by itself doesn’t have a special meaning in regex.

Comment: Which TYPO3 version do you use?

Comment: Typo3 Version 7.6 I use

Comment: You can update to a supportet version TYPO3 CMS 10 and use new concept of routes. There you can config all your needs. Or use EXT:realurl for TYPO3 CMS 7

Comment: beside of updating and using build in slugs, also with realurl you do not need any rewrites in htaccess as (nearly) every URL first is generated inside of TYPO3 as a link and this link already should have nice URLs. only if you have generated this kind of URLs, TYPO3 / realurl later is able to translate it back to the format the extension php is able to understand. So: don't care about .htaccess but build a proper realurl configuration (and slug configuration after an update to >=9)